# How to fix laravel composer update issue ( Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump failed to open stream: No such file or directory)

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm currently working on a laravel project using an existing package for e-commerce functionality called Bagisto. I already downloaded the package files from the repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/bagisto/bagisto) and dopped the files inside xampp htdocs folder on my Ubuntu 18.04 OS.
The problem happens after I launch `composer update` in the terminal inside my project directory I get this error message:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
PHP Warning:  Uncaught ErrorException: require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:66
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(66): Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'require(/opt/la...', '/opt/lampp/htdo...', 66, Array)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(66): require()
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(56): composerRequire75e2944913aa928a280073a462abdd28('37a3dc5111fe8f7...', '/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit75e2944913aa928a280073a462abdd28::getLoader()
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ComposerScripts.php(43): require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(297): Illuminate\Foundation\C in /opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

Warning: Uncaught ErrorException: require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:66
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(66): Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'require(/opt/la...', '/opt/lampp/htdo...', 66, Array)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(66): require()
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(56): composerRequire75e2944913aa928a280073a462abdd28('37a3dc5111fe8f7...', '/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit75e2944913aa928a280073a462abdd28::getLoader()
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ComposerScripts.php(43): require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(297): Illuminate\Foundation\C in /opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP Fatal error:  composerRequire75e2944913aa928a280073a462abdd28(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

Fatal error: composerRequire75e2944913aa928a280073a462abdd28(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/bagisto/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
```

And the composer.json file content is:

```
{
    "name": "bagisto/bagisto",
    "description": "Bagisto Laravel ECommerce",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.0@dev",
        "dimsav/laravel-translatable": "^9.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.9@dev",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "flynsarmy/db-blade-compiler": "*",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "intervention/imagecache": "^2.3",
        "kalnoy/nestedset": "^4.3",
        "konekt/concord": "^1.2",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "3.1.x-dev",
        "nwidart/laravel-modules": "^3.2",
        "prettus/l5-repository": "^2.6",
        "propaganistas/laravel-intl": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.1",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpro/grumphp": "dev-master",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "replace": {
        "bagisto/laravel-user": "v0.1.0",
        "bagisto/laravel-admin": "v0.1.0",
        "bagisto/laravel-ui": "v0.1.0",
        "bagisto/laravel-core": "v0.1.0",
        "bagisto/laravel-attribute": "v0.1.0",
        "bagisto/laravel-checkout": "v0.1.0",
        "bagisto/laravel-customer": "v0.1.0",
        "bagisto/laravel-inventory": "v0.1.0",
        "bagisto/laravel-category": "v0.1.0",
        "bagisto/laravel-product": "v0.1.0",
        "bagisto/laravel-shop": "v0.1.0",
        "bagisto/laravel-theme": "v0.1.0",
        "bagisto/laravel-shipping": "v0.1.0",
        "bagisto/laravel-payment": "v0.1.0",
        "bagisto/laravel-sales": "v0.1.0",
        "bagisto/laravel-tax": "v0.1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Webkul\\User\\": "packages/Webkul/User/src",
            "Webkul\\Admin\\": "packages/Webkul/Admin/src",
            "Webkul\\Ui\\": "packages/Webkul/Ui/src",
            "Webkul\\Category\\": "packages/Webkul/Category/src",
            "Webkul\\Checkout\\": "packages/Webkul/Checkout/src",
            "Webkul\\Attribute\\": "packages/Webkul/Attribute/src",
            "Webkul\\Shop\\": "packages/Webkul/Shop/src",
            "Webkul\\Core\\": "packages/Webkul/Core/src",
            "Webkul\\Customer\\": "packages/Webkul/Customer/src",
            "Webkul\\Inventory\\": "packages/Webkul/Inventory/src",
            "Webkul\\Product\\": "packages/Webkul/Product/src",
            "Webkul\\Theme\\": "packages/Webkul/Theme/src",
            "Webkul\\Shipping\\": "packages/Webkul/Shipping/src",
            "Webkul\\Payment\\": "packages/Webkul/Payment/src",
            "Webkul\\Paypal\\": "packages/Webkul/Paypal/src",
            "Webkul\\Sales\\": "packages/Webkul/Sales/src",
            "Webkul\\Tax\\": "packages/Webkul/Tax/src",
            "Webkul\\API\\": "packages/Webkul/API"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packagist.org"
        },
        {
            "packagist": false
        }
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "App\\Test::test",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "stable",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

I already tried some ways to resolve this problem like updating the composer and the laravel framework version but still not getting any solution.

Comment: try composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle .   then run composer update .   then composer dumpautoload

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, it starts with : ``` Using version ^6.3@dev for guzzlehttp/guzzle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files 
``` 
then gives the same error

Comment: php artisan config:cache and then php artisan cache:clear   man i'm sure it's something super simple and I personally know how frustrating this can be.  Stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

If the answer of Ankit Singh not working.

- You had run `composer install` and you got a general error in terminal window, for example: `Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump failed to ...........`.
- If you have a bad syntax into your php files code (like a wrong `use Class;` statement) then the error above not show much details.
- Try to run `php artisan migrate`, and then will show where the problem is with full path and the line number of the problematic file.
  (for example: `Warning:  The use statement with non-compound name 'Log' has no effect in \path\to\your\file.php on line 5`)
- So, with that detailed error we can go to specific file and resolve the problem (in this case, remove `use Class` from php class includes)

  Hope someone find help in this!

Comment: Please share more details. How should `artisan` run if PHP already throws such an error on basic operations?